# Есть ли библиотеки для добавления виджета на домашний экран android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Мне надо добавить виджет приложения из самого приложения. Я знаю такая возможность появилась в Android 8 Я написал реализацию. Но беда в том что она работает очень плохо. Например это не работает на Xiaomi и помоему даже Samsung. Я уже молчу про то что это не работает на смартфонах ниже Android 8.0 В то же время браузер типа Firefox легко добавляют виджеты на все Android и на все марки устройств (Xiaomi, Samsung). Я так понял они используют свою библиотеку: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Add_to_home_screen Но судя по тому что я прочитал, такую библиотеку можно использовать только для браузеров, там будет открываться страница сайта. Но у меня же не браузер. Может есть какая нибудь библиотека чтобы так же добавляла виджет на экран? Или может можно исходный код этой библиотеки, может можно его как то переписать под себя? Посоветуйте пожалуйста что нибудь.

Comment: Пользователь сам должен добавить виджет на экран

Comment: Не пойму? Я же написал "надо добавить виджет приложения из самого приложения" Я написал реализацию, но толку это очень плохо работает. Может этой библиотекой можно добавлять, но судя по тому что прочитал это только для браузеров.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Короче я не то использовал. На самом деле мне надо было использовать не виджеты а вот это ShortcutInfoCompat.Builder Если кому интересно вот добавляется очень просто:

```
public void createLauncherDesktopShortcut(Intent intent, @DrawableRes int iconRes, String title) {
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        if (intent.getAction() == null) {
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        }

        ShortcutInfoCompat shortcut = new ShortcutInfoCompat.Builder(_context, Long.toString(new Random().nextLong()))
                .setIntent(intent)
                .setIcon(IconCompat.createWithResource(_context, iconRes))
                .setShortLabel(title)
                .setLongLabel(title)
                .build();
        ShortcutManagerCompat.requestPinShortcut(_context, shortcut, null);
    }
```

Если кто нибудь скинет мне почитать доп. информацию про шорткаты, то я не против. Потому что когда я читал официальный гайд. Я подумал что шорткат это когда иконку долго жмешь и вылазит меню. А про это ничего не сказано, я и подумал что надо виджеты делать.

Answer (score 1):

Вы правильно написали, что начиная с версии 8.0 появилась возможность добавлять `AppWidgets` программно и конечно это нужно использовать. Никакие библиотеки тут не нужны.

Да, на Xiaomi версии 8 есть устройства которые делают это с ошибками (на самом деле они ничего не делают возвращая некорректный результат), но на Samsung'ах и прочих устройствах все работает хорошо (с небольшими исключениями).

Важный момент: если у вас есть активность конфигурирования, то вы должны ее вызывать сами, кроме того есть возможность вывести в качестве предварительного просмотра не картинку а целый Layout (в Андроид 12 это уже потеряло свою актуальность).

Рекомендую использовать эту возможность с версии 9.0

Comment: Я это понимаю но если это работает, то работает плохо, в то же время Firefox на android может добавлять виджеты прямо с приложения в любых версиях android и на любых марках. Он же как то это делает + работает хорошо все это https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/fenix

Comment: Там установить жмешь и виджет добавляется.

Comment: @Madoka Magica  Ну почему плохо? Работает нормально, на Google Pixel, эталонном телефоне, тоже. Не знаю я как FireFox это делает если это не поддерживается аппаратно, мне если честно лень это проверять.

Comment: Ну вроде он это делает через вот эту библиотеку  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Progressive_web_apps/Add_to_home_screen  Вот только, я так понял что она применима только к браузерам или типа того, буду еще искать пробовать.

Comment: Кстати моя реализация только что на эталонных телефонам и работала. Даже на самсунге с Android 11 увы не запускало.